# Handling events between controller and views

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have a simple application which displays a set of "activities" and it works but I thought I'd start using some Ember View's (this is a learning experiment for me) instead of the current controller-template-model that I'm using right now.

In displaying activities, there is a standard view, a detailed view, and a toggle switch that hides/shows the details. I thought that maybe the view could handle the toggle switch and the hiding/showing aspects. Sadly that leads me to my problem ...

It appears that a view can capture "click" and other events but I want it to capture my Activities template's {{action}} statement and it appears that action events skip the view and start looking for the handling function in the controller (and then router). Is that right?

To codify my problem, the **Activities template** is as simple as this:

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{view App.ActivityView}}
{{/each}}
```

The ActivityView points to a template for most of the work but also contains the action handler `toggleDetails` (as well as `click` just inserted for testing purposes):

```
App = require("app");

module.exports = App.ActivityView = Ember.View.extend({

    templateName: 'activity',
    isDetailHidden: true,

    click: function(evt) {
        // just added for debugging purposes ... this does get executed
        console.log("ActivityView clicked");
    },

    toggleDetails: function(target) {
        console.log("ActivityView pressed " + target);
        this.set('isDetailHidden', !this.get('isDetailHidden')); // toggle state
        target = "#activity-details-" + target;
        if (this.get('isDetailHidden')) {
            jQuery( target ).slideDown( "fast" );
        } else {
            jQuery( target ).slideUp( "fast" );
        }
    }

});
```

The toggle switch is defined in the **Activity template** as:

```
 <a href="#" class="arrow"><div class="icon" {{action toggleDetails id}}></div></a>
```

And it's worth pointing out that each Activity is given an DOM id with the following statement (used to target the specific activity with the jQuery animation):

```
<ul class="activities " id="activity-{{unbound id}}">
```

In any event, the {{action}} is, as previously mentioned, skips over the view and looks in the controller and router for the handler instead. It then -- afterward -- calls the View's "click" method which I've put in just for debugging purposes.

I'm a bit of newbie Ember so any hand-holding you might be able to provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set the target of the action:

```
{{action toggleDetails this target=view}}
```

(I also added 'this' to pass scope)

Comment: BTW, if I move to another route and then return, are these views re-initialised or do they keep their state?

Comment: They ARE re-initialised, but their state can be managed through the model, and controller...try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amindunited/g4HW6/) ...just click back and forth between the pages, and you'll see the page view counts are independently managed.